# How to delete or remove selected datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

So i wanna delete/remove selected datagridview after i pass to another datagridview

```cs
private void BtnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow item in dgAvailabe.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkchecking = item.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkchecking.Value) == true)
        {
            int n = dgSelected.Rows.Add();
            dgSelected.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dgSelected.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dgSelected.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dgSelected.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dgSelected.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You can use `bindingSource.Remove()`. Or `dataGridView.Rows.Remove()` using `in dgAvailabe.Rows.ToList()`.

Comment: YOu mean DataGridViewRow? or Full DataGridView Object?

Comment: datagridviewrow